# Node-gyp Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.9.dylib

Tags: c++, node.js, node-modules, node-gyp, node-native-addon

I have been attempting to make a nodejs-native-addon which uses libmtp to carry out certain functions. I have been successful in the building the app but the app is throwing `Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.9.dylib. Referenced from: /path/build/Debug/nbind.node. Reason: image not found` error when I try to run it on another macbook where the libmtp isn't installed.

This is my *binding.gyp* file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "includes": [
        "auto.gypi"
      ],
      "sources": [
        "src/native/mtp.cc"
      ],
      "link_settings": {
        "libraries": [
            "-lmtp"
        ],
      },
    }
  ],
  "includes": [
    "auto-top.gypi"
  ],
}
```

I even attempted to include the dylib file in the libraries option

```
"link_settings": {
    "libraries": [
      "<(module_root_dir)/src/native/lib/libmtp.9.dylib"
    ]
}
```

but the app fails to start with the `Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.9.dylib. Referenced from: /path/build/Debug/nbind.node. Reason: image not found` error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that the library `libmtp.9.dylib` cannot be found in the standard library include path `/usr/local/lib` 
Try setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the location where you have the `libmtp.9.dylib` before running the node.

Comment: Wow that's great, let me take a look. A quick question though is it possible to bundle such libraries automatically along with the release file? What if I have another 3rd party library imported in the code and it will get difficult to keep track of the dependencies to ship along with the app. Is there anyway to automatically resolve and bundle the dependent libraries along with the app?

Comment: You can add another target section to the targets[] array of the binding.gyp file to copy the library to the `build/Release` or `build/Debug` folder. Here is a sample section: 
`{
         "target_name": "copy_lib",
         "type":"none",
         "dependencies" : [ "your_addon_name" ],
         "copies":
         [
            {
               'destination': '<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/',
               'files': ['<(module_root_dir)/src/native/lib/libmtp.9.dylib']
            }
         ]
      }`

Comment: I did exactly the same. Tried export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/absolute/path/library and even LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/absolute/path/library/libmtp.9.dylib before running the nodejs file. But i keep getting Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.9.dylib. Referenced from: /path/build/Debug/nbind.node. Reason: image not found error. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a symlink in a known rpath like `/usr/local/lib` manually to your built library. Not ideal but it may provide a workaround for at least having successful builds in development.

```
ln -s <absolute_path>/src/native/lib/libmtp.9.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmtp.9.dylib
```

This allows the `binding.gyp` file to find the library without it needing to configure an rpath with whatever process is throwing the error. This is easier in my opinion than tracking down the `binding.gyp` trace.